# How to fix the makefile targets into the gradle targets?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm setting up a new build.gradle for build environment.
So for that I want to convert the existing makefiles targets into gradle targets

The following code is of the makefile:

```
Default: Dest
    @${ECHO} ""
    @${ECHO} "Done building ${COMPONENT_NAME} $@."

Dest: Dest-Native
    @${ECHO} ""
    @${ECHO} "Done building ${COMPONENT_NAME} $@."

Clean: All-Dirs Clean-Native

All-Dirs :
        @${ECHO} ""
        @${ECHO} "Done building ${COMPONENT_NAME} $@."

Clean-Native :
        @${ECHO} ""
        @${ECHO} "Done building ${COMPONENT_NAME} $@."
```

Please help me in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

check the official gradle tutorials:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

the simple task definition:

```
task hello {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello world!'
    }
}
task intro {
    dependsOn hello
    doLast {
        println "I'm Gradle"
    }
}
```

so the command line `gradle intro` will execute `hello` and `intro` tasks

```
#a_gradle>gradle intro
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :hello
Hello world!

> Task :intro
I'm Gradle
```

Comment: Tell me how they are going to be execute... looking for the dependency

Comment: right. gradle executes tasks according to dependencies.

Comment: btw. are you going to use gradle for c++ project?

Comment: No it is for java

Comment: in this case if you use java plugin, you'll have pre-defined tasks and you don't really need to define new ones. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Comment: also check multi-project builds doc: https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/

Comment: 's exactly! But the first I need to create the installer and for that no java plugins, not even compilation is needed